# Need help with BMX Frame logo stamping

Tags: bmx

I need help with this logo, I cannot find any clear answers... The frame is aluminum, the rear dropouts have this logo stamped and the bottom bracket does have two sets of serial numbers.

[image]

Comment: I've been working on finding your logo. Would you post a picture of the frame along with your current picture? It would give me more to go on.

Comment: a picture of the entire bike would help a lot more, looks aluminum from the welds?

Comment: I have the same bike stamp was anyone able too determine what kind of bike for sure . Mine has just a frame was hoping to put her back in her original Glory

Comment: The one time where the serial number would have been helpful...all modern era Treks have a WTU... serial number

Answer (score 7):

This is Trek - not certain of the exact era.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Nathan has done the hard work of identifying the stamp. A great place to research BMX bikes is bmxmuseum.com. Navigate to the ["Trek" link in the "T" section of "Bikes" navigation](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/trek/).

There are several aluminum Trek BMX frames that might match what you have.
One example is the [Trek SubCulture SS](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/search?company%5B0%5D=133&model=1028) Based on the examples at bmxmuseum.com it looks like the bike was made from 1996 to 1998
Drop out for the SubCulture SS
[image]
Here is a nice write up on a 1997 SubCulture. I'll include the parts list.
**Frame**:  1997 Trek Subculture - 7005 series aluminum     serial #  WTU100133M
**Fork**:  1997 Trek - 4130 chromoly, 1 1/8" steerer tube, 3/16" dropouts
**Headset**:  Aheadset SX-1
**Stem**:  Trek - stock alloy
**Bars**:  S&M Dive - stock width
**Bar Ends**:  Odyssey Gedda 2
**Grips**:  Odyssey Gedda 2
**Brake Lever**:  Diatech Tech 99
**Brake Cable**:  Odyssey slic
**Cable Housing**:  Pyramid
**Rear Brake:**  Tektro 876 AG V-brakes - stock
**Clamp**:  Trek - alloy double bolt
**Seat Post**:  Kalin - 26.8mm alloy
**Seat**:  Trek Team Issue - "Rocket Man"
**Bottom Bracket**:  Trek - stock American size
**Spindle**:  Vigorousport - stock
**Crank Arms**:  Vigorousport - hollow 4130, stock
**Pedals**:  Wellgo B102 - 9/16"
**Chain Wheel**:  Trek spider with 44 tooth ring - stock
**Free Wheel**:  ACS Claws - 17 tooth
**Wheels**:  stock

- Front Rim:  Araya 7x - 36 hole, single wall
- Front Hub:  Formula - cartridge bearing, 3/8" axle
- Rear Rim:  Araya 7x - 36 hole, single wall
- Rear Hub:  Formula - cartridge bearing, 3/8" axle
- Spokes:  stock - 14 gauge
- Nipples:  stock brass

The [Trek SubAtomic](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/search?company%5B0%5D=133&model=2921) is another possible candidate. It looks like the 1996 model was aluminum.
Here is the back of one in orange
[image]

Both bikes might have the same frame. Makers often use the same frame with different parts and label them as different models.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a THRODWN. The BMX brand was started in 2015.

Comment: I am pretty sure I remember seeing this logo back in the 90s, but, if I am not mistaken, it was like a walmart bike brand, not a major "Contender"